# How to compare different files from 2 servers with rsync?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, server, rsync

I got trouble with some hackers, they hacked into our website, so I cloned our server to a new one, and then reset the github on that server.

I heard about rsync can find out what is different about 2 servers. Is it possible for rsync ? Can I export that list of files to a text file?

Thanks your help, got hacked by use old version of wordpress >_< I was crazy with this from last couple days.

Comment: rsync -avun $TARGET $SOURCE

from [here][1]


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57305/rsync-compare-directories

Answer (score 1):

The comment by Marty is good - the rsync command as written will do a dry-run (`-n`) to show you what files were added/deleted/changed between the `$TARGET` and `$SOURCE` locations so you can then inspect or diff them to see if there is any malicious code.

Additionally, in the past when I've dealt with hacked WordPress installs, it is important to find the exploitation vector.  Often times PHP shells get uploaded via some insecure script or plugin which gives the attacker a command based web shell to view files and run commands etc.

To find these files, the following command is helpful:

```
grep -E '(?:(shell_)?exec|system|eval)' /path/to/wordpress/* -R
```

This might yield something like:

```
wpte.php:               eval($_POST['p1']);
```

Which in this case, `wpte.php` was a malicious PHP shell script that got uploaded to one of my client's servers that someone then used to run commands and upload more files.  These scripts usually use one or more functions like `eval` or `shell_exec` to run commands input from the web shell.

Going from there, you can check the server access logs for hits to the malicious script and then further search the logs for the IP address(es) that accessed that script to potentially find how the uploaded the script or other hits resources they accessed.